# Como detectar el giro de la pantalla y cambiar los datos del GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-layout, recyclerview

Como muchos sabemos que al momento de girar la pantalla del teléfono o tablet lo que hace la aplicación es cargar nuevamente la activity, necesito detectar ese giro y cambiar el valor del GridLayoutManager y pasarlo al recyclerview, el contenido que carga mi app lo hace desde un xml en un servidor y todo el proceso esta dentro de un Asyntask, en el metodo onPostExecute creo el GridLayoutManager y se lo paso al recyclerview.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda, dejo parte del codigo donde necesito colaboracion.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressBar_home.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Necesito pasar el spanCount de 2 a 3.

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asi determinas según la orientacion, tamaño y densidad de pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El valor que le otorgas segun la configuración:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y desde codigo java lo invocas de esta forma:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressBar_home.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_width));
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: No sabia como crear el directorio del integers land, lo que hice fue crear una carpeta llamada values-land, gracias, esta fue la respuesta mas sencilla y concreta.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que podrías hacer es detectar cuándo se realiza el giro de pantalla para poder actualizar el adapter de tu GridLayout en ese momento en concreto. Si sobreescribes `onConfigurationChanged` podrás detectar el momento en el que el usuario hace un cambio en la rotación de la pantalla y así poder adaptar tu aplicación:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration myConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(myConfig);
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    Log.d("CHANGESCREEN", "Orientation: " + orientation);
    switch(orientation ) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            // Con la orientación en horizontal actualizamos el adaptador
            adapter.notify();
            break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            // Con la orientación en vertical actualizamos el adaptador
            adapter.notify();
            break;
    }
}
```